# Laravel Nexmo message for response status

Tags: laravel, vonage

I'm working on an implementation of Nexmo in Laravel using facade.
I want to show a message with the send status (or any response of failure), and the remaining balance in my Nexmo.

```
Nexmo::message()->'to'=>''from'=>''please check and help`
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When sending an SMS, capture the response using `$resp = Nexmo::message()->send(['to' => '', 'from' => '', 'text' => '']);`.

You can then access the information you need using `$resp->getStatus()` and `$resp-> getRemainingBalance()`